# Sending email to yahoo account

Tags: c#, java, .net, email, networking

How do you send an email to a yahoo account, I can only send to gmail ? I'd like to know why because MY ISP doesn't offer me a POP3 or SMTP address. I don't know anything about mine, if you could tell me a way to investigate then I'll be delightedly thankful.

```
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("pevus55@gmail.com", "mypassword");
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;

    MailAddress mailFrom = new MailAddress("parris797877@yahoo.com");
    MailAddress mailTo = new MailAddress("pevus55@gmail.com");
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(mailFrom, mailTo);
    msg.Subject = "Test";
    msg.Body = textBox1.Text;
    smtp.Send(msg);
```

Comment: please show some source code of how you are sending email to gmail...

Comment: question kind of not clear what you required

Comment: I edit my post to add the code you request.

Comment: I really hope that's not your actual password...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set your SmtpClient to whatever your outgoing SMTP server is.  The code that is successfully sending to GMail is using Google's SMTP server directly.  That's OK and is a bit quicker when you're sending to GMail, but they won't want to relay to Yahoo for you.  To do so would invite abuse by spammers.

You can find out what your outgoing SMTP server is by looking in the settings of your email client, or by looking at the tech support website for your ISP.

Alternatively you can send directly to yahoo's SMTP server.  You'll need to find out what it is.  "dig mail.yahoo.com MX" on a *NIX or Mac OS X system will tell you, but to do it automatically you will need to write the code to do a DNS lookup of their MX record.

Some ISPs do not permit outgoing mail to be sent to any SMTP server other than the one that's provided by the ISP.  They do that to keep spammers contained.  If that's the case you won't be able to talk directly to yahoo's SMTP server, you'll need to talk to your ISPs.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are using your GMail credentials to connect to the mail server, but see the following.. you are trying to send from Yahoo to GMail.. not from GMail to Yahoo...

```
MailAddress mailFrom = new MailAddress("parris797877@yahoo.com");
MailAddress mailTo = new MailAddress("pevus55@gmail.com");
```

If you want to do this you should connect to the Yahoo server with it's credentials..

Thanks...

Comment: Yes, I would like to send an email to a yahoo account, but I can not use the credentials with yahoo mail server `smtp.yahoo.com`. My connection gets timeout error. Do you know the mail server and its port for email in yahoo case ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to setup your yahoo email account to allow for that - see these links:

- http://techblissonline.com/yahoo-pop3-and-smtp-settings/
- http://email.about.com/od/accessingyahoomail/f/Yahoo_Mail_SMTP_Settings.htm
- http://help.yahoo.com/l/ca/yahoo/mail/pop/pop-03.html

As SMTP server for Yahoo use `smtp.mail.yahoo.com` - please check the SMTP information in the online-help of your Yahoo-account... it provides vital information on how to access Yahoo account via POP3 (get mails) and SMTP (send mails)...